# Python install in Windows. Interpreter not recognized?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

in windows 10 I've just installed python 3.10 from official python site.
But invoking `python` from *cmd* or *powershell.exe*, I got microsoft store opened showing python download instead.
The path *C:\Users\mhd\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps* where *python.exe* resides already in my environment variable.
Any clue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're Python installation isn't registered at the command line.

This is can be done through the Python installer when installing by opting to add Python to your Windows Environment Path variables. Note that User Paths (created under your User folder) will not be available to all users, whereas System Paths (typically created outside your Users folders) often will be.

Also be aware that with User or System Path variables, you may need to reboot Explorer (`explorer.exe`) to have e.g. `python` available from all folders at the command line. You can restart any `explorer.exe` processes from Task Manager manually, but you can simply reboot the PC as well.

Note that since you have already installed Python, you can likely simply [add the path to your Python installation manually to your System Path variables](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows).

You can double check that e.g. `python` is registered at the command line correctly by typing `where python` in a non-PowerShell `cmd` Window. The first path returned should be for your Python installation. If it isn't, then you may need to alter your Path variables so that your installation comes first in order entries.